# What is the syntax to open a file with Visual Studio Code from the Hyper terminal (using Windows 10)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, hyper

I have installed the VSC's extension "Hyper in VS Code" and Git. I know for opening files with Atom on the mac you type "open Atom filename". What is the equivalent to this on Windows 10 for VSC? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `code filename`, but you should ensure that vscode is in your `Path`.

According to vscode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line), to do that:

1. Launch VS Code.
2. Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type `shell command` to find the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command`.
3. Press enter to enable it.

Restart the terminal for the new $PATH value to take effect. You'll be able to type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder or type `code filename` to open that file in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening the folder in VS Code from a terminal with the command
`code .`.

Answer (score 0):

**How To Open The code in Text Editor/ VS Code ,Atom , Subline so on with the help of Terminal or Git bash  ?**

Simple Check some  Configuration which i provide below the image :-

1. First run this command pwd (which directory  you  are  currently)
2. Second run this command ls (list of directories)

> 3. Final Which Directory you want to open so you shloud run this command :-

If You Mac user

```
open code file_name.extenstion or / folder_name

open Atom file_name.extenstion or / folder_name
```

if you window user then :-

```
start code file_name.extenstion or / folder_name
```

[image]